# Zend Framework 2 custom view helpers - cross modules

Tags: view, frameworks, zend-framework2, helper

In Zend Framework 2, how can I have one view helper available to multiple modules?

What I want is to have some general functions, like algorithmic functions, that can be reused by multiple modules.

I'm currently on ZF 2 2.0.3

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its simple, put it in one of your modules. You can use classes and functions from other modules in ZF2. Because modules in ZF2 aren't much more than just namespaces, with some classes in them. So, if you create a view helper with the name `\Module\View\Helper\MyHelper`, you can simply use that view helper in another module.

Comment: This is correct.  If it's just general-purpose stuff, you can stick all of it in it's own module (or break it up into more specific modules), like "DimmyUtilModule".  Then you can re-use that module across different projects.  You might even consider giving that module its own repository, so you can pull it into future projects with composer.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Yes, having its own module is a great suggestion.  Regards.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what kokx said, you will also need to add service manager configuration for the view helper manager. This can be done in one of two ways: in your module configuration, or in your Module class.

```
// module configuration:
return array(
    'view_helpers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'dimmy' => 'DimmyUtil\View\Helper\DimmyUtil',
        ),
    ),
);
```

or, in a Module class:

```
namespace DimmyUtil;

class Module
{
     public function getViewHelperConfig()
     {
         return array('factories' => array(
             'dimmy' => function ($helpers) {
                  // do some stuff...
                  return $helper;
             }
         ));
     }
}
```

Once you do so, the view helper will be available throughout any application composing the module.