# Database query inside layout or view in zend2

Tags: zend-framework2

How to access zend database connection inside views.

In my case my USERS index.phtml display list of all the users and USER is registerd with multiple languages which are stored as JSON format in the database

Here is the indexAction.

```
return new ViewModel(array(
        'users'             => $this->getRegisterTable()->fetchAll(),
    ));
```

And inside index.phtml

```
<?php foreach ($users as $users):?>
<?php 
$getQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lang where id= $users->lang ");
$getResult = mysql_fetch_array($getQuery);
$lang = "<a href='" . $this->url(lang , array('action'=>'detail', 'id'=> $users->lang )) . "'>" .$getResult['name']."</a>";
 ?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

So to get this query executed I have to manually intialize the database cannection using MYSQL_CONNECT

But I want it to access zend initialize database connection only.

Comment: use the view helper. where you can interact with the database.

Comment: Please drop any example link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201244/zend-framework-2-custom-view-helpers-cross-modules , http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/zend-framework-2-create-your-custom-view-helper/ , http://codingexplained.com/coding/php/zend-framework/custom-zend-framework-2-view-helper

Comment: This is really the wrong approach. You should be doing the querying in a model layer, and fetching the complete results from there via your controller.

Comment: I have to strengthen the point of @Crisp It is the Controllers job to pass all the required Data to the View. The View then only has to iterate through the data for rendering purposes only. A ViewHelper should never contain such business logik, ever.

Comment: definitely do not do this, if you have a query inside your view you are doing it all wrong regardless of weather it works or not. A view is for presentation only. The results should either be passed from your controller, or inside your ViewModel

Comment: Well I removed this query, as it was just an examle forwhat I really wanted. But ViewHelper was the answer for my query. @Crisp ,are you guys saying that this HELPER approch is wrong??

Answer (score 1):

As others have correctly stated, then this is a very bad thing to do. Such data should be sent to the view from your controller, and your view should not make use of the database or even know that a database is being used. By breaking the MVC (Model View Controller) design pattern, your code will be much harder to maintain and understand.

If I understand what you want to do correctly, then you want to display the languages that users have been registered with. I would fetch this information when fetching the users such that the languages are available on your `User` model. If you use a Mapper class to fetch your users from, then this is where you would fetch the languages. Then in your view, you should just do like this instead:

```
<?php foreach ($users as $user) : ?>
    <?php foreach ($user->getLanguages() as $language) : ?>
        <?php $lang = "<a href='" . $this->url('lang' , array('action'=>'detail', 'id'=> $language['id'] )) . "'>" . $language['name'] . "</a>"; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now you no longer have business logic or data access logic within your presentation (view) layer. Remember to escape data from the database by using the `escape` view helper, like this:

```
<?php echo $this->escape($language['name']); ?>
```

I hope it helps. Once you get up and running with an architecture where you fetch your data from a separate layer, you will start to understand why this is the best practice.