# set view suffix for view files in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

The default zend framework 2 configuration relies on phtml files for view rendering. However, for security reasons I want to change that to php.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201244/zend-framework-2-custom-view-helpers-cross-modules) link I understand that I need to create a custom view helper in order to do that or is there a setting I can change to change the suffix from phtml to php and how is this done exactly?

Update: I got it working, but not the way I want. If possible I would like to get the answer from guessimtoolate working. So I prefer something like this in my module.config.php:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'default_suffix' => 'php',
    //etc...
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my memory serves my well, you can define that in `default_suffix` key in your module's configuration file under `view_manager`, e.g.:

```
return array(
    // ...
    'view_manager' => array(
        'default_template_suffix' => 'php',
        // ...
    ),
    // ...
);
```

This should make template file resolvers to look for `.php` files instead of `.phtml`.

Not entirely sure how's that an improvement, but it can be done.

**UPDATE:**
Sorry, I've wrote the wrong configuration key name -- it should be `default_template_suffix` and not `default_suffix`. It is used, e.g.: in `Zend\Mvc\Service\ViewTemplatePathStackFactory` where path stack resolvers are born :).

Comment: I got it working with the other answers, but I prefer your answer. However your code doesn't work.

Comment: offtopic I want to do this because I think phtml is not a standard php file extension. Yes it can be included and executed as php, but if called directly, then php just shows the whole content!

Comment: @J.Rahmati Though it should not be possible to call the files directly, as your host should root into the `/public` directory. Therefore the world doesn't have direct access to your .phtml files, making this a non-security-issue.

Comment: @Sam I know, but I don't have the right permissions to deal with that and want to do it this anyway (even if the host roots into the public directory) just to be on the safe side may something go wrong!

Comment: Isn't there anyone who knows how I can get this working using this answer?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I've made a typo in config key name and went away. And again, I'm not convinced that is the best of solutions to change template file extensions to script file extensions.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. Now it works. Offtopic: It wasn't meant as a complete solution. Of course there are a lot of other things which can be done. I just wanted to also have control about what happened if someone managed to call this file directly (i.e. when all other solutions failed because of a misconfiguration).

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your module.php:

```
//module.php
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $application = $e->getApplication();
    $sm = $application->getServiceManager();        

    $sm->get('ViewTemplatePathStack')->setDefaultSuffix('php');
}
```

Then change all `.phtml` files to `.php` in your project.

Answer (score 0):

In your Application module, the Module.php file:

```
public function onBootstrap($e)
{
    $app = $e->getApplication();
    $sl  = $app->getServiceManager();

    $resolver = $sl->get('ViewTemplatePathStack');
    $resolver->setDefaultSuffix('php');
}
```

What happens here, is during bootstrap you grab the path stack and sets the suffix on the resolver.